# How do I print a text file to the default printer a line at a time in WPF / C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, text, printing, default

This seemed such a simple task until I put all the requirements in my question together.  In fact it's an upgrade of a Visual Basic 6 program so I know the methodology is sound (although I'm open to any alternative suggestions).

I am a long-time programmer (30+ years) but new to WPF and C#.  I have a plain-text file containing some placeholders, e.g. {StockCode}, and my program will read the file a line at a time and substitute values from a selected row in a WPF (4.5) DataGrid for any placeholders before sending that line to the printer.  I don't want a Printer Settings dialog to appear as the output will always go to the default printer.

Through much reading on the web I found several references to Microsoft's RawPrinterHelper class at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091 but upon trying to implement that I found it appeared to be geared towards Windows Forms (it is a 2006 article after all).  I also found reference to PrinterSettings.IsDefaultPrinter but again that appears to be old functionality.

Further reading indicated I should be using System.Printing for WPF but that seems to point to the PrintDialog Class and PrintDocument Method which are contrary to my requirements.  It did occur to me as I was typing this that a workaround would be to read the text file and write the contents with substituted values out to a temporary text file and then print that, but I'm sure there's a way to do what I want that I'm just not seeing.

Thanks

Wayne Ivory

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.visualstoxpsdocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link.  However this appears to generate an XPS document whereas I specifically need the document to be printed as generic text.  I didn't include this detail in my original post because it unnecessarily distracts from the requirements, but I'm actually sending the result to a barcode printer.  The printer accepts plain text, however recognises certain embedded commands and decides whether to print the data as text or barcode.